# Probability of a biased coin

Tags: probability

If we toss a biased coin that is twice as likely to come up heads as tails, $5$ times,

what is

a. the probability of observing $2$ heads out of the $5$ tosses

b. the probability of observing at least $2$ heads out of the $5$ tosses

c. the probability of observing at most $2$ heads out of the $5$ tosses

I think it is a basic problem but I am finding a hard time on figuring it out.

Is it binomial distribution?

Comment: Yes it is a binomial with $p=\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of observing $k$ head out of $n$ coin tosses is $P(n,k)=\binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k\cdot (1-p)^{n-k} $, where $p$ is the probability to observing head, and as consequence $1-p$ is probability of observing cross. In this problem $p$ is twice as $1-p$, so $p=2\cdot(1-p) \to 3p=2 \to p=\frac{2}{3}$.
For example, point a. gives:

$P(2,5)=\binom{5}{2} \cdot \bigl( \frac{2}{3}\bigr)^2\cdot \bigl(\frac{1}{3}\bigr)^{3} \approx 0.16 $